# How to insert variables in Supabase database migrations

Tags: environment-variables, database-migration, supabase, supabase-database

I am using a local Supabase CLI to develop my database structure to then deploy to my Supabase project using migrations.

In one of the SQL functions I need to provide the service key and the project URL:

```
declare
  project_url text := '<YOURPROJECTURL>';
  service_role_key text := '<YOURSERVICEROLEKEY>'; --  full access needed
```

This is an issue for two reasons:

1. The project url and service role keys differ between my local and online databases, so I would have to manually update these before deploying my changes.
2. These migration files will be uploaded to GitHub, and I don't want to share my service role key.

Is there a way to insert these values as variables in the .sql migration files instead?

From my search I haven't found a good way to inject these variables. Is this possible at all, or what best practice can I follow to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should never have to use Supabase URL and service role key inside your Database functions. Your database functions have full access to all of your database, without you providing those credentials.

Comment: Not according to the example here https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs#storage-management